# when a route param is added to req.params?

Tags: node.js, express

I have URL:

```
app.get('/api/v1.0/m/:vipId', descM);
```

and a function like this:

```
function descM(req, res) {
  accesslogger.info("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
  accesslogger.warn('req',req.params);
  var vipId = req.params.vipId;
  var tenantId = req.get('X-Product-Id');
 ......}
```

I wrote a filter to handle the params:

```
function loggerFilter(req, res, next) {   
   logger.warn('==================');  
   logger.warn("req",req.params);
    ...... (handle) 
}
```

but the output is different for these two functions:

```
    [2015-08-02 14:40:16.857] [WARN] access-log - [xxxx] ==================
    [015-08-02 14:40:16.859] [WARN] access-log - [xxxxx] req {}
    [2015-08-02 14:40:16.866] [INFO] access-log - [xxxxxx] bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    [2015-08-02 14:40:16.868] [WARN] access-log - [xxxxxx] req { vipId: 'fec1209c-30b7-4a19-9f78-0785cacd78b9' }
```

the route param should can get in the filter,but the example shows the param is not in, only in the function??
how can i get the param in the filter for a rout param

Comment: app.use(loggerFilter);

Comment: please post expanded example showing when you call `app.use` and when you call `next()` inside the filter

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work with Express 4: middleware does not have access to `req.params` (see [this](https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2088)).

There are various solutions:

```
app.route('/api/v1.0/m/:vipId')
   .all(loggerFilter)
   .get(descM);
```

Or:

```
app.get('/api/v1.0/m/:vipId', loggerFilter, descM);
```